How can I have bitcoind recreate my wallet.dat?
I had to kill bitcoind, then deleted my datadir and restarted bitcoind. I assumed it would recreate and resync everything, which it did, except for the (empty) wallet.dat.
What I did was delete the separate datadir, empty the .bitcoin folder, except for the bitcoin.conf file containing my rpc credentials. I tried twice, the second time orderly stopping and restarting bitcoind, but without a new wallet.dat recreated.
What should I do get a new wallet.dat, preferably through a fresh restart (to avoid carrying over any file corruptions as a consequence of unorderly killing the daemon process)?

A wallet.dat file will be created only when you decide to create a wallet.

Since Bitcoin Core 0.21.0 (released in January 2021), no default wallet is created anymore.
This follows a change in Bitcoin Core 0.15.0 (released in September 2017) to support multiple loaded wallet simultaneously. Since then, it has no longer been the case that wallet files are necessarily called wallet.dat; they can have any name.
The ability to create new wallets through the RPC interface was added in Bitcoin Core 0.17.0 (released in October 2018), through the createwallet command.


I'm not sure to have seen the actual .dat file, probably only the (empty?) wallets folder. Could it be that bitcoind only creates that folder when it can't find a .bitcoin folder? I left it in place, to keep my .conf file, for my rpc credentials. Will the folder be created when I create a wallet with bitcoin-cli?
